# What happens when a user with lots of declined flags casts the only flag at a moment in time?

Tags: support, flags

When somebody with many rejected flags casts a new flag, this flag is shown behind flags other users with a better flag weight have cast.

What happens when this flag is the only flag cast in a specific moment? Does it appear in the flag queue with a delay, or does something else happen?
Furthermore, what happens when, for example, a user with a low weight cast a flag, and after an hour a user with a higher flag weight cast a flag before the previous one is handled?

Comment: I read that question several times before I understood what you actually meant. I tried to improve that question - please check that it still asks what you intended...

Comment: What would be the reason to add a delay?  What benefit would be gained?  The purpose of placing a low priority on users with a low flag weight is because it's unlikely to help, not to punish the user doing the flagging to make them wait.  The top item in the queue is the item with the most flag weight behind it; if the item with the most flag weight is an item with very little flag weight, it's still the first item.

Comment: @Servy I don't think kiamlaluno requested a feature adding this functionality. I think he just asked what happens to flags with a low flag weight if the queue is empty. So I guess you answered his question: The flag with the most flag weight (even that is quite low) is still the first in the queue.

Comment: @Servy See Spontifixus's comment. It is not a feature request, nor am I implying there should be any delay in showing the flag. I have also never said the flag weight is for punishing the user; I know perfectly the flag weight is to handle for last the flags cast from who usually use flags in a wrong way.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I know it's not a feature request.  You're asking if the devs made it act that way.  I'm asking why they would want to do that as a way of indicating that I see no reasonable reason for implementing that behavior.  If it makes no sense for it to behave that way, and you have no evidence which would indicate that it's the current behavior, then why ask the question to begin with?  What prompted it?